# Can't recover all values from Json page using Axios and React Native

Tags: react-native, axios

I get the result below from the url "https://api.myjson.com/bins/1f1pxv"

```
{
  "categoria": "Graduação - Semipresenciais",
  "cursos": [
    {
      "name": "Engenharia de Computação",
      "tarefas": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Engenharia de Computação",
      "tarefas": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Psicologia",
      "tarefas": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

I use React Native and Axios to get the values

```
buscaCursosJson = () => {      
    axios.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1f1pxv").then(response => {
      alert('x2: '+response.data.cursos.name)
      alert('x1: '+response.data.categoria)
    })

};
```

The alert 'x1' is showing correctly the result "Graduação - Semipresenciais", but the 'x2' alert is showing 'undefined' as a result.

How I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find how to fix the problem, I use the map function

```
response.data.cursos.map(data => alert(data.name))
```